# 1998 honda civic lx automatic transmission

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, civic

I am having issues with transmission. It was working fine and this happened with No kinda of a warning. I left my job and drove about 1/4 mile and stopped at a stop sign, when I pulled away it shifted once and its like it disengaged like it was in neutral. It wouldbt engage in any gear. I can put it in park cut off the engine and restart it and it will engage in any of the gears and it will go fine for 1 minute to maybe 10 min and it will stop like it is in neutral and I can put it in park cut it off restart and it will go fine for a little ways then quit again....Can anyone help witha possible diagnostic on this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level?

Comment: Yes. The fluid level is full.